# Is it possible to get country-wise retention in firebase? How?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

DAU can be filtered country-wise by adding specific code but it seems retention cannot be filtered. Is  there a way to get countrywise retention?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: please look at [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The current Firebase UI (as of May 2018) does not allow filtering by country. The only way to do it is to link your Firebase data with Google's BigQuery and then manually query the retention data from there.

Comment: could you provide more details? or maybe you have some instruction

Comment: Here's the guide: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery